# Is there a maximum limit of readable file stream or writable file stream created same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, stream, filesystems

I have a couple of doubts

First:
Is there a limit to the maximum amount of file (readable or writable) streams that can be created?

```
Like a [...[readable, writable]] streams array of n files
```

Second:
Does the maximum number of files open in the operating system apply only when using the stream event on 'open' ?

```
Like in linux by default is 1024 per process
```

Third:
Does this directly affect the maximum number of streams that can exist on 'open' simultaneous event?

```
Like 1024 simultaneous 'open' stream event per process
```

if anyone has information about it thanks for sharing it and for your time, sorry for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First: Is there a limit to the maximum amount of file (readable or writable) streams that can be created?

A node.js file stream uses an open file handle from the operating system so whatever OS limitations apply to how many simultaneous open file handles a process can have would also apply to open file streams in nodejs.  So yes, there is a limit and that limit is determined by the operating system.

> Second: Does the maximum number of files open in the operating system apply only when using the stream event on 'open' ?

No.  A file system handle is used in any stream that is reading/writing from a file.

> Third: Does this directly affect the maximum number of streams that can exist on 'open' simultaneous event?

The limitation has nothing to do with whether you're listening for the `open` event or not.  Every stream that is reading or writing to a file uses an operating system file handle, regardless of whether you're listening directly for the `open` event or not.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is clear and easy to understand.